# How to use a linebreak inside a cloud (node) enviroment in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Usually I never had problems with linebreaks inside of tikz. But this time around for some reason unbeknownst to me, tikz doesn't wanna give me a linebreak. Do you have an idea what might be causing this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[cloud callout, cloud puffs=10, aspect=4.5, cloud puff arc=70,
    shading=ball, anchor=pointer] at (0,0) {
        This is long text\\
        One line isn't enough
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `align` in `\node`,

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[cloud callout, cloud puffs=10, aspect=4.5, cloud puff arc=70,
    shading=ball, anchor=pointer,align = left] at (0,0) {
        This is long text\\
        One line isn't enough
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

`left` or `center` or `right`.